# What funtions exist about search for SharePoint Online Add-ins?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to make a SP Add-in and I want to know if there are functions that I can use to reproduce the funtionality of a Content Search Web Part, I dont know if I can use some funtions to take advantage of the crawler (REST, JSOM or CSOM, some API).

Answer (score 1):

This will help you get started: [Using the SharePoint 2013 search Query APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn423226.aspx)

C# example:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://<serverName>/sites/<siteCollectionPath>"))
{
    KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
    keywordQuery.QueryText = "SharePoint";
    SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
    ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

JavaScript example:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("<serverRelativeUrl>");
var contextSite = clientContext.get_site();
var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(clientContext); 
keywordQuery.set_queryText("SharePoint"); 
var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(clientContext);  
var results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery); 
context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryError);
```